# webGL texture extensions

Tags: html, webgl

I am really new to webGL and I don't know how to add an extension. I tried just doing "gl.enable(gl.OES_texture_float_linear)", but that seems to be wrong.

Could you please tell me how to get the extension to work?

Thank you, and sorry for my ignorant question.

Answer (score 2):

This might help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebGL/Using_Extensions.

Basically, you do:

```
var ext = gl.getExtension('OES_vertex_array_object');
// or which ever gl.getExtension('extension_name');
if (ext) {
  // extension exists
} else {
  // extension does not exist
}
```

Latest available extensions can be seen on: http://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/

Comment: extensions have nothing to with loading images from data URLs

Comment: Erm, so? The question was "how to get the extension to work?". I am answering to that particular question.

Comment: I guess I was reading between the lines. The question originally said "I'm having trouble loading a image from a URL and I think I need an extension, how do enable extensions" but extensions have nothing to do with loading images from URLs. I edited the question so it doesn't mention loading images from URLs. If that was his real question he'll ask again I guess.